# How do I pause and resume audio in a different method than from the method it was made in?

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to make a game and attempting to make a "mute" and "unmute" button, but I cant figure out how to make it so when you push the button it stops the same clip that is being played at the beginning of the program. (using different methods of course).
I attempted to make the clip and audio public, but I keep getting an error and I'm not sure why.

```
public class TowerDefense 
{
    String filepath = "MenuTheme.wav";
    private Clip clip;
void playMusic(String musicLocation) 
{
    try{
        File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);

        if(musicPath.exists())
        {
        AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInput);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.`LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY`);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void pauseMusic(String musicLocation2)
{
long clipTimePosition = clip.getMicrosecondPosition();
clip.stop();    
}
==============
//this is in a different private method called Options
panel.setButtonsActionListener2(**new** ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    frame.dispose();
        TowerDefense musicObject = new TowerDefense();
        musicObject.pauseMusic(filepath);
    Options();
        }
    });
```

I was expecting an output of the clip stopping and then you can either make it play again or keep it muted. In this case it just says error when I press the "mute" button.

Comment: ok one second is this the new java?? did i miss the big revolution?? /**long**/

Comment: sorry, I got rid of them now

Answer (score 0):

So, in the code that runs when you click your mute button, you are making a new TowerDefense object that is supplied the music's filepath. Here is the issue with that. The clip that is already playing exists in the program. Creating a new TowerDefense object will not automatically give you access to the clip that is playing.

Ensure that you call the pauseMusic method on **the same object** where you called the playMusic method.

Thus, if you already have created a TowerDefense object in the program and called playMusic, then give your action listener access to that object and use the existing object to call pauseMusic.